# how to get first dropdown box value if i select second dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the code where I have created two dropdowns dynamically. If i select the second dropdown I would like to get the first dropdowns selected value.

Below is HTML:

```
<div class="selct_drp_dwn" id="row1">
    <select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name1" onchange="changeBox2(this);">
        <option>Sample1</option>
        <option>Sample2</option>
        <option>Sample3</option>
        <option>Sample4</option>
    </select>
    <select class="drop_dwn_mult1" id="name1" onchange="changeBox3(this);">
        <option>Please select</option>
        <option>sam</option>
    </select>
    <i class="fa fa-minus-square remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true" id="btnAdd"></i>
</div>
```

Below is the jQuery I tried:

```
function changeBox3(val1)
{
    var a = val1.id;
    alert(a);
    var c = '#'+a;      
    var b = $(c).closest('select .drop_dwn_mult option:selected').val();
    alert(b);//I am getting undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the closest method. It should be:

```
.closest('.selct_drp_dwn')
```

and then you should find the select:

```
.find('.drop_dwn_mult').not(val1).find('option:selected')
```

---

With that in mind, you can still short your code to:

```
function changeBox3 (val1)
{
  var a = $(val1); // <- you passed `this` to val1 which is already a reference
                   //    to the element, thus not need to find the id
  var b = a
           .closest('.selct_drp_dwn')
           .find('.drop_dwn_mult')
             .not(val1)
           .find('option:selected')
           .val();
  alert(b);
}
```

---

Another issue: Ids must be unique, you have duplicates of `name1`.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Hi Guedes.. i have one more question if i have a submit button, once gets submitted how i will get the selected value from both dropdown as single value

Comment: What do you mean by _single value_? One stringified object like `'{"val1":30,"val2":25}'`? I suggest you open a new question with more detailed content.